# how to preserve nodejs chat application widget between page loads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat

I'm working on chat application(with chat widgets for site visitors) using nodeJS. My problem is that I'm not sure how to preserve the visitor details between page loads.Once the visitor started the chat,I don't want him to re-enter his email and name when he visits another page.If I use I cookies or somethingI(I'm not sure wheather I can use cookies because the widget will be in someone else's website), how can I know that it's the same visitor or a new one? Using some kind of timer?

This is my first nodeJS application and I'm still in the basic level.A pointer to the right direction or a search term for Google would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if browser local storage fits your needs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Thank You for the links!

Comment: sure,But I'm still going through the links :)